# Firebase trouble when initializing CLI to deploy a react app

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I keep getting the error below:

> ? Are you ready to proceed? Yes
> ? Which Firebase features do you want to set up for this directory? Press Space to select features, then Enter to confirm your choices. Hosting: Configure files for Firebase Hosting and (optionally) set up GitHub Action deploys
>
> === Project Setup
>
> First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
> You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add,
> but for now we'll just set up a default project.
>
> ? Please select an option: Use an existing project
>
> Error: Failed to list Firebase projects. See firebase-debug.log for more info.
> `PS C:\Users\xxxxxlinked-in>`

I have tried everything I can find on StackOverflow:

`firebase login` will log me in.
I have also done the `firebase login --reauth` one and also just reinstalling it `npm install -g firebase-tools`.

Its just when I go to use an existing project.

If it helps to know, I keep gettin another error when uing this command `firebase projects:list`.

Comment: The error says: "See firebase-debug.log for more info" Did you do that? What did it say?

Comment: firebase-debug.log : The term 'firebase-debug.log' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check 
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ firebase-debug.log
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (firebase-debug.log:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: I tried tio go to the "IAM & Admin" section of the Google Cloud Console, click on the "Roles" tab. and switch the roles in my project. However I did not see "Firebase Project Manager" and "Service Account User" which CHatGPT suggested changing the Rolds to for the admin firebase-adminsdk@<project-id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com.

Comment: Are you asking [how to find a specific file in PowerShell?](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+find+a+specific+file+in+PowerShell)

Comment: No sir, just trying to host on firebase but after I select the longin, do firebase init it prompts some choices one of which says  "Use an existing project". When I select it gives me that error. However, I am starting to think this is a firewall issues as I am on my work computer.

Comment: And as I said in my first comment, the error message say to look in the firebase-debug.log file for more info. Did you look in that file? What did it contain?

Comment: I could not figure out how to view that log. I downloaded the google analytics ext and tried to view the process but did not see any data showing up.

Comment: "I could not figure out how to view that log." It's a plain text file, so you should be able to open it in any text editor - including notepad.

Comment: [info] 
=== Project Setup
[info] 
[info] First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
[info] You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add, 
[info] but for now we'll just set up a default project.
[info] 
[debug] [2023-01-07T19:28:07.773Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects pageSize=100
[debug] [2023-01-07T19:28:08.182Z] Failed to make request to https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects?pageSize=100

Comment: [debug] [2023-01-07T19:28:08.486Z] FirebaseError: Failed to make request to https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects?pageSize=100
    at RetryOperation._fn (C:\Users\Jeremy.xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\apiv2.js:242:31)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[error] 
[error] Error: Failed to list Firebase projects. See firebase-debug.log for more info.

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information, instead of posting it in comments. That also allows you to use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to make them more readable.